# How to authenticate an on demand API call made via splunk?

Tags: python, api, splunk

I am thinking of developing an API in Python using Flask library.
I learnt the below.
It has a `/auth` to just take any `username` and `password` and `save` it in database i.e. for registration.
It has a `/login` to take `username`, `password` and `validate` it with database and then send a `token`.
It then has a `/xx` call to take the `token`, `validate` the identity of user and return him with the requested `data`.

I am now trying to understand the below.
If I make an API call via custom script execution on SPLUNK to this API that I will develop, how will I pass `Splunk` login credentials to the API and how will the API make sure that they are correct?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get Splunk to call an API, or are you trying to call a Splunk API from an external script. You have explained the process for calling a Splunk API, but should you want Splunk to call an API, you can follow the mechanism outlined at https://www.splunk.com/en_us/blog/tips-and-tricks/securely-storing-accessing-passwords-for-alert-action-scripts.html or https://www.splunk.com/en_us/blog/tips-and-tricks/securely-storing-accessing-passwords-for-alert-action-scripts.html for saving credentials in Splunk securely.

Comment: I need to call an API via custom https call. Thanks, going through it.